# From a specific place in the array, add another value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is such an array of months:

```
let months = ['July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',];
```

There is such a function:

```
    function headerCellRendererFunc(params) {
        var eHeader = document.createElement('span');
        var eTitle = document.createTextNode(params.colDef.headerName + ' ' + year);
        eHeader.appendChild(eTitle);
        return eHeader;
    }
```

On the way out I get:

- July'17
- August'17
- September'17
  e.t.c...

I need that from January to **year** there was **+ 1**

What would have happened so:

- July'17 August'17 September'17 October'17 November'17 December'17
  January'18 February'18 March'18 April'18 May'18 June'18

How to make a condition in a function?

```
    months.map((month, index) => {
        var year = this.fy;

        function headerCellRendererFunc(params) {
            var eHeader = document.createElement('span');
            var eTitle = document.createTextNode(params.colDef.headerName + ' ' + year);
            eHeader.appendChild(eTitle);
            return eHeader;
        }

        return <ColDef>{
            headerName: month,
            headerCellRenderer: headerCellRendererFunc,
            field: `data.${month}`,
            editable: isEditable,
            valueGetter: cellMonthValueGetter(month, index),
            cellFormatter: cellMonthValueFormatter,
            newValueHandler: cellMonthNewValueHandler(month),
            width: 100,
        };
    }).forEach(colDef => colDefs.push(colDef));
```

Comment: How are these two chunks of code related?

Comment: Is the `months` array always going to have only 12 months and in order?

Comment: @tadmani add more code

Comment: @dork yes, always 12 months in this order

Comment: @ValitskiyDmitriy all right. Thanks for the info. You can check my answer out https://stackoverflow.com/a/46294414/769326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const months = [
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December',
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
];

/**
 * Sets the year of the month and returns the new array of months.
 * @param {number} year - The two-digit year.
 * @param {string[]} arrMonths - The array of string months in order.
 * @returns string[]
 */
function setYear(year, arrMonths) {
  return arrMonths.map((month, i) => {
    // Increment the year if this is not the first pass and the month is January.
    if (i !== 0 && month.toLowerCase() === 'january') {
      year++;
    }

    return `${month} '${year}`;
  });
}

console.log(setYear(17, months));
```

**Update**

I took the `headerCellRendererFunc` outside the map; you just need to bind the year to it since `ColDef.headerCellRenderer` passes the params to the function.

As for the `year`, you just need to check if January is the first month or if the current month index is less than the index of January. If it is, set it to `this.fy`. If it's not, `this.fy + 1`.

```
function headerCellRendererFunc(year, params) {
  const eHeader = document.createElement('span');
  eHeader.innerText = `${params.colDef.headerName} ${year}`;
  return eHeader;
}

const januaryIndex = months.indexOf('January');
months.map((month, index, arr) => {
  const year = januaryIndex === 0 || index < januaryIndex ? this.fy : this.fy + 1;

  return <ColDef>{
    headerName: month,
    headerCellRenderer: headerCellRendererFunc.bind(null, year),
    field: `data.${month}`,
    editable: isEditable,
    valueGetter: cellMonthValueGetter(month, index),
    cellFormatter: cellMonthValueFormatter,
    newValueHandler: cellMonthNewValueHandler(month),
    width: 100,
  };
}).forEach((colDef) => colDefs.push(colDef));
```

Comment: It is necessary to change only the value of the year, do not add it to the month

Comment: So what exactly is the output you want? An array of numbers?

Comment: There is a year, this number is equal to 17. After January, you need to make it 18. And by months I'm adding it to another function. The code is in the question.

Comment: Not really quite clear (almost everyone who answered has kind of the same answer), but maybe you just need to add a condition to `var year = this.fy;`. You can do `var year = index !== 0 && month.toLowerCase() === 'january' ? this.fy + 1 : this.fy;`. Also, it would be better if you placed `headerCellRendererFunc` outside the map. Just `bind` the params and year to it in `<ColDef>`.

Comment: Thank you! It works for me! Only 18 only in January, as the following months also make a +1?

Comment: Oh okay okay. I think I get your question, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I understood how you did it, I will use it in the future! You are the best!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var months = ['July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'];
var januaryIndex = months.indexOf("January");
var finalMonths = months.map((month, index) => (index < januaryIndex ? month + "'17" : month + "'18"));
console.log(finalMonths);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the months array from january and take the value with the remainder operator. For the year, you could divide the months by 12 and take the ineger value.

```js
function getValues(startMonth, startYear, count) {
    var months = ['December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November'],
        i,
        result = [];

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result.push(months[(startMonth + i) % 12] + ' ' + Math.floor(startYear + (startMonth + i - 1) / 12))
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getValues(7, 2017, 12));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the conditional you need to map the months to values...

```
let months = ['July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',];

let monthMap = {Janurary:1,Feburary:2,March:3,April:4,May:5,June:6,July:7,August:8,September:9,October:10,November:11,December:12}

if(monthMap[month] >= 1 && monthMap[month] <= 6)
                 //format...
```